# How to allocate `Optional` accounts on heap?

Tags: anchor, account, heap

I am trying to use optional accounts and since there are many accounts, i tried boxing them. But looks like the `derive macro` panics when i try to box the optional accounts like below.

```
escrow_account: Box<Option<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>>,
```

But it works fine if i remove the `Option` from above.

Please tell me how i can box the optional accounts since i am running out of stack memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to heap allocate optional accounts in Anchor. The reason why your example doesn't work is because the `Option` type is required to be the outer type for the optional accounts:

```
escrow_account: Option<Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>>,
```

[Example](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/dfee9589fd56f9aa1a52aa949507b70035482857/tests/optional/programs/optional/src/context.rs#L9)

Comment: I see, so I was able to allocate those accounts on heap but still running out of stack memory. I commented the instruction code, but it is still panicking so i guess its because of the accounts. If i have boxed all accounts possible and still running out of stack space, what is the solution?

[Accounts where stack is overflowing](https://github.com/ComposableFi/emulated-light-client/blob/a0173b3c8ea32f220cb901253dea2db220375d9f/solana/solana-ibc/programs/solana-ibc/src/lib.rs#L249)